# How to filter inbound traffic for GCP CDN?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-cdn, google-cloud-armor

I have a very basic question about cdn service in gcp. I need to allow  just some ips in inbound and deny all the other traffic. How I can achieve this feature? just to know, the cdn will use a backend bucket service.

I've already tried gcp armor but for HTTP(S) load balancer it does not work.
Then, what is the right component in the gcp stack?

Thank you in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Armor for Cloud CDN is available now as mention [here](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/identity-security/new-waf-capabilities-in-cloud-armor). It's only available for backend services now. For backend buckets, there seems to be no timeline on that.

Answer (score 0):

In the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/security-policy-concepts#restrictions) says:

> Cloud Armor security policies and IP deny list/allow list are not
>   supported for Cloud CDN. If you try to associate a Cloud Armor
>   Security Policy for a backend service and Cloud CDN is enabled, the
>   config will be rejected. Similarly, if you attempt to enable Cloud CDN
>   for a backend service that has an associated Cloud Armor security
>   policy, the configuration process will fail.

Also there is a [Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/130620190) already present.

Comment: Thank you Albert, do you have any eta for this feature request?

Comment: Usually there is no ETA for this kind of request, since they need to be evaluated. Also since there is no ETA, maybe we should mark the answer as done.